# Is there a way to selectively use providers or services from one module into another instead of injecting whole module as dependency into another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, es6-modules

I have two angularjs modules. First module contains some services, components, styles, directive, providers and so on. Second module has its own services, components, directives and so.

I need only the styles, services and providers from module First in module Second. If i add First as a dependency in Second, whole module will load along with all components, which is not needed in Second.

So is there a way by which i can inject selectively i.e. services and providers from module First in Module Second without loading all unnecessary components and other code in angularjs 1.x ?

Comment: but what's the harm if all the things are imported?

Comment: Yes, re-factor common services into their own module.

Comment: Some other modules are using full module First ( all its components, services and all) so can't make a copy and make a module of services separately.